# Spring boot app fails Method org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.createClob() is not yet implemented

Tags: java, spring-boot, postgis, hibernate-spatial

I am using spring boot command line runner app, it hangs at PostGIS dialect, the below stack trace contains what's happening. Unable to understand what's going wrong, I have hibernate-spatial queries.

```
2018-04-06 12:11:08.554  INFO 31495 --- [           main] replayer.Main                            : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-04-06 12:11:08.780  INFO 31495 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@39d9314d: startup date [Fri Apr 06 12:11:08 NZST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-04-06 12:11:10.811  INFO 31495 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2018-04-06 12:11:11.149  INFO 31495 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a0866479] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-04-06 12:11:12.038  INFO 31495 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2018-04-06 12:11:12.113  INFO 31495 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-04-06 12:11:12.113  INFO 31495 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.28
2018-04-06 12:11:12.146  INFO 31495 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib]
2018-04-06 12:11:12.385  INFO 31495 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-04-06 12:11:12.386  INFO 31495 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3615 ms 
2018-04-06 12:11:12.704  INFO 31495 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
2018-04-06 12:11:12.710  INFO 31495 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-04-06 12:11:12.711  INFO 31495 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-04-06 12:11:12.711  INFO 31495 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-04-06 12:11:12.711  INFO 31495 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2018-04-06 12:11:13.264  INFO 31495 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2018-04-06 12:11:14.376  INFO 31495 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Driver does not support get/set network timeout for connections. (Method org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.getNetworkTimeout() is not yet implemented.)
2018-04-06 12:11:14.834  INFO 31495 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2018-04-06 12:11:15.073  INFO 31495 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-04-06 12:11:15.111  INFO 31495 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
name: default
...]
2018-04-06 12:11:15.306  INFO 31495 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.0.Final}
2018-04-06 12:11:15.310  INFO 31495 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2018-04-06 12:11:15.313  INFO 31495 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2018-04-06 12:11:15.332  INFO 31495 --- [           main] o.h.spatial.integration.SpatialService   : HHH80000001: hibernate-spatial integration enabled : true
2018-04-06 12:11:15.418  INFO 31495 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.0.Final}
2018-04-06 12:11:15.891  INFO 31495 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect
2018-04-06 13:10:34.209  INFO 2217 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.LobCreatorBuilderImpl        : HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl.useContextualLobCreation(LobCreatorBuilderImpl.java:113) [hibernate-core-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl.makeLobCreatorBuilder(LobCreatorBuilderImpl.java:54) [hibernate-core-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentImpl.<init>(JdbcEnvironmentImpl.java:247) [hibernate-core-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:114) [hibernate-core-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) [hibernate-core-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88) [hibernate-core-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234) [hibernate-core-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:208) [hibernate-core-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189) [hibernate-core-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51) [hibernate-core-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94) [hibernate-core-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217) [hibernate-core-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189) [hibernate-core-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352) [hibernate-core-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111) [hibernate-core-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:770) [hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:797) [hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) [spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) [spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:388) [spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) [spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) [spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1769) [spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1706) [spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:583) [spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) [spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) [spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) [spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) [spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1085) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:858) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
at replayer.Main.main(Main.java:29) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: Method org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.createClob() is not yet implemented.
at org.postgresql.Driver.notImplemented(Driver.java:734) ~[postgresql-9.3-1104-jdbc41.jar:na]
at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.createClob(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:58) ~[postgresql-9.3-1104-jdbc41.jar:na]
at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.createClob(Jdbc4Connection.java:21) ~[postgresql-9.3-1104-jdbc41.jar:na]
... 42 common frames omitted

2018-04-06 13:10:34.211  INFO 2217 --- [           main] org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry     : HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@364b1061
2018-04-06 13:10:34.430  INFO 2217 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-04-06 13:10:34.462  WARN 2217 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'main': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'eboxEventRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'repository.EboxEventRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
2018-04-06 13:10:34.463  INFO 2217 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-04-06 13:10:34.463  INFO 2217 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2018-04-06 13:10:34.486  INFO 2217 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2018-04-06 13:10:34.488  INFO 2217 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2018-04-06 13:10:34.507  INFO 2217 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-04-06 13:10:34.641 ERROR 2217 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

**************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field eboxEventRepository in replayer.Main required a bean of type 'repository.EboxEventRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'repository.EboxEventRepository' in your configuration.
```

My Main class looks like this, I want it to be a command line runner, hence implementing the CommandLineRunner.

The application should just read data from a specific table and dump that to json content and onto a disk.

```
package replayer;


import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import my.model.Event;
import my.model.EventMessage;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.Banner;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import repository.EventRepository;

import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Main implements CommandLineRunner {

@Autowired
EventRepository eboxEventRepository;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Main.class);
    app.setBannerMode(Banner.Mode.OFF);
    app.run(args);

}

@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    List<EboxEvent> eboxEvents = eboxEventRepository.findEboxEventBetweenEventTimestamps(null, null);

    final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("/tmp/events.tmp");

    for (EboxEvent event : eboxEvents) {
        EventMessage message = new EventMessage.Builder(EventMessage.Type.DATA_CHANGED,
                        EventMessage.Operation.CREATE,
                        my.model.Event.class.getName()).eventId(UUID.randomUUID().toString()).dataAfter(Arrays.asList(event))
                        .build();
        String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(message);
        out.println(json);
    }
}
```

}

And my pom depenedencies are like this

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0.Final</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0.Final</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
                <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0.Final</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.3-1104-jdbc41</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.21</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `createClob` failure may be the likely cause. Similar issue on github
https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/issues/1102

and solution referenced is

http://vkuzel.blogspot.in/2016/03/spring-boot-jpa-hibernate-atomikos.html

which is to disable usage of JDBC metadata and set the correct dialect.

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults = false
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
```

or in YAML:

```yaml
spring:
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        temp:
          use_jdbc_metadata_defaults: false
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
```

Answer (score 1):

```java
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
```

Just add this to your application.properties and it will work may be.
it worked for me.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Thank you for participating and helping the community. To add value to your answer and help those with less knowledge than you, please add an explanation as to how and why this will work.

Answer (score 1):

This error is caused by Hibernate. The answers did not work for me, because I use a hibernate file configuration.

In your `hibernate.cfg.xml` file add property:

```
<property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">false</property>
```

Maybe also set propper PostgreSQL dialect adding:

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect</property>
```